# How to find out if the commits in a git submodule are in a specific branch in the original repo

Tags: git, github

I have a repo `bar` that takes a git submodule of `foo` to path `/repo/foo`.

I want to run a script in `bar` to veryify that the submodule `foo` has commits only coming from the `main` branch.

Is there a way to do this without manually iterating each commit in a submodule and in turn verifying if it is in the original repos `foo` branch?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I know to make a list of everything submodule foo has ever been set to:

```
git log --all --raw --diff-filter=d --no-abbrev --pretty= -- foo | awk 'print $4'
```

to make a list of everything in submodule foo's main branch:

```
git -C .git/modules/foo rev-list origin/main
```

So verifying means checking that everything in the first list is also in the second.